# System requirements for and alternatives to loading RDF into Jena Fuseki

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki

I have a large rdf file:

- size: 470MB
- number of lines: almost 6 million
- unique triple subjects: about 650,000
- triple amount: about 4,200,000

I want to load this rdf definition into a native rdf store on my notebook.

The computer's specs are:

- Intel B980 CPU
- RAM: 4GB
- no SSD
- free HDD space: ~8 GB

I decided to use Jena Fuseki,

downloaded the latest version:

http://mirror.dkd.de/apache/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-3.12.0.tar.gz

started Fuseki:

```
java -Xmx1200M -jar fuseki-server.jar
```

and uploaded the rdf definition via the web frontend:

http://localhost:3030/dataset.html?tab=upload&ds=/gnd

According to the progress bar the parsing/importing progress advanced rather fast at first, then became gradually slower, stopped after about 15 minutes (at roughly 50%), and after 20 minutes started anew.

So my questions are:

Are the specs of my computer not suited for an rdf file as large as this? Is there a rule of thumb concerning the requirements?

Are there alternatives / better ways to import the data into Fuseki? Maybe in chunks?

Comment: I would try the TDB command line utilities for faster loading. The specs look workable, but more memory would be better. If memory is limited and there is no SSD, I wouldn’t expect great performance.

Comment: "I wouldn’t expect great performance": Are you referring to import time or query execution time?

Comment: Certainly query execution time, but probably also import. I don't have hard data on this.

Comment: Be careful with what else is running on the machine.  Its 4G for everything. Other applications and the filesystem cache are taking from that space.